# Mekor that Learning Coincides with Each Other

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study

Many times when I am learning from 2 separate sources, it amazes me the Hasgacha Pratis how well they coincide with each other (*especially* when it comes to the various Yomis), that one will mention something I had just learned/am about to learn in the other.

For example, when Mishna Yomi was up to Brachos 2:3 (discussing the need to hear yourself say Shema), literally the next day it was brought in the Daf on Megillah 17b.

Similarly, many times learning coincides with current events.
For example, Daf this cycle finished Pesachim on 9 Nissan 5782, just days before Pesach. A few days later, Shekalim 8b discussed the 4 Kosos mamash on the 2nd day of Pesach.

While many people have told me they have also noticed the same phenomena, I have yet to find a Mekor/**specific source** inside that mentions these kinds of Hashgacha Pratis in learning.

Does anyone know of such a source?

Comment: This requires a statistical analysis to seee if the phenomenon is actually significant, or of it could be explained by pure statistical randomness. Take, for example, your daf yomi example. If there are 354 days in a year then with pure randomness you would expect the daf to fall on its significant day at least every few hundred years. Then if there are a few hundred dafs that have significant dates, it wouldn’t be surprising if there was such a coincidence every year. You could also calculate the actual calendar and predict such events in advance, so is that really Hashgacha Pratis?

Comment: Related to my above point: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/110713/is-there-any-relatively-simple-way-to-calculate-when-how-often-the-daf-yomi-cy

Comment: The problem with this analysis is that you remember days where this coincidence happens, but are not writing questions why is it that during so many other days you did NOT see such coincidence. In other ways, even totally random phenomena sometimes produce interesting coincidences

Comment: I guess I should have not focused so much on the Daf. I meant that many times I do find that even when I am learning something and happen to see say a random Dvar Torah sheet lying around (sometimes many weeks old), it will bring up what I just learned. I understand it may just be chalked up to statistical chance, but I was looking to see if any Mareh Makom mentions that there is a specific zechus to experience this.